# Code works in Firefox but not in IE or Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This is a script that pulls data from a text feed and displays the Stock value from within that feed.  It works just fine when I test the movie but when I try to publish it in a web page it does not display the live data in IE or Chrome.  I'm just using the default publish options and I'm also trying to use it on a Digital Signage player that is essentially rendering a web page in IE.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var rawRSS:String = e.target.data;
    var pattern:RegExp = /<TD.*?TD>/sg; 
    var pieces:Array = rawRSS.match(pattern);   
    var CH = pieces[2].split(">");
    var CHR = CH[1].split("<");
    var CHRW:String = String(CHR[0]);
    var CHRWT:String = CHRW.substr(0,5);

    stock_price.text = CHRWT;

    var loc:int = pieces[4].indexOf("+",0);
    var gain:String = String(pieces[4].charAt(loc));
    //trace(gain);

    if (gain == "+"){
        stock_price.textColor = 0x00CC33;
    }
    else {
        stock_price.textColor = 0xFF0000;
    }

}

loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.nasdaq.com/aspxcontent/NasdaqRSS.aspx?data=quotes&symbol=CHRW"));
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a server or just running the HTML page from disk?

Comment: running the html page in IE or Chrome from my computer doesnt produce the stock price.  Firefox does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your swf from a web server, it is not allowed to fetch data from another domain, unless that domain allows it in a crossdomain.xml file, and [Nasdaq's](http://www.nasdaq.com/crossdomain.xml) doesn't.

Comment: that doesnt explain why firefox plays it locally and ie/chrome dont.

Comment: @Seth, Have you tried running it from a server in firefox? Maybe firefox is more lenient with localhost testing.

Comment: Well, you edited the question, so it no longer mentions "an HTML Page" and "web server", as it did before, when I posted my answer.

Comment: I've got a hunch that you're correct Lars, though I think there are also some other issues at play with the content displaying on the Exhibio Digital Signage engine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your last Line of Code. Shouldn't the param data be directly attached to the question mark?

By the Way, I also noticed that IE8 and previous doesen't accept Event handlers if attached programatically to the DOM. But I guess, you tested it in different browsers already.

Comment: The whitespace isnt there in the actions panel.  I'm using IE9 and Chrome to view it with no success.